# Let's get critical: Dec 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Craft CMS Stack Exchange](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Call a public function within a FieldType file, from a variables files](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4250/call-a-public-function-within-a-fieldtype-file-from-a-variables-files)

**Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Make entry in nav not clickable and reroute](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/make-entry-in-nav-not-clickable-and-reroute)

**Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What's the best way to skip CSRF for plugin controllers?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4553/whats-the-best-way-to-skip-csrf-for-plugin-controllers)

**Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What is getContent() / the ContentModel, and how do I use it to get and set custom field values?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4486/what-is-getcontent-the-contentmodel-and-how-do-i-use-it-to-get-and-set-cust)

**Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Double escaping Regular Expressions in Craft's Twig replace filter?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4270/double-escaping-regular-expressions-in-crafts-twig-replace-filter)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Password protected area with unique files](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4182/password-protected-area-with-unique-files)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Craft license: what is considered a "dev-sounding subdomain"?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4417/craft-license-what-is-considered-a-dev-sounding-subdomain)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is there a better way to localise channel url?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4299/is-there-a-better-way-to-localise-channel-url)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Custom order related entries](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4654/custom-order-related-entries)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Javascript event on save for custom field](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4611/javascript-event-on-save-for-custom-field)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---